# Jsoup parsing after Authentication

Tags: java, authentication, selenium, jsoup

I am trying to parse a webpage using Jsoup, but the problem is that the page needs authentication.

The approach i want to take is to use Selenium WebDriver to do the authentication, and then parse the data on the page using Jsoup. But I am not too sure how to implement this, cause i might need cookies or some headers to the request for the authenticated page.

Any thought on how to implement this ? I know this is very abstract, but am still trying to figure out how to get this moving.

edit : I am just starting off using jsoup, so I don't know if such authentication is possible using just jsoup without the use of Selenium Webdriver or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTTPClient or HttpUrlConnection to submit your details directly then the page will do you authentication,after that you will get the next page as response.
Give that response to Jsoup,parse it and access your data.
Check this link:http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/